# Get data from promise in redux

Tags: react-redux

When Reducer update state and I get state from store it returns a promise. Inside promise in values I have my data How can I access this value in promise.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAtWz.png)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To use async actions with Redux, you are going to want to use a middleware, mostly either `redux-thunk` or `redux-saga`. See [Why do we need middleware for async flow in Redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34570758/10614791)

As a beginner at Redux you should probably start with the [official documentation on the topic](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic).