# Explanation this JavaScript React Redux Code

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

There are 4 files:

1. React Component File:

   [image]
2. Action-Creator File:

   [image]
3. Action file:

   [image]
4. Reducer File:

   [image]

Now I have used this code for about 100s of times already but I am still not able to understand certain things. Like for instance, how does point 1 dispatch effect point 2 function? What does const variablename = (data) => asycn(dispatch) => {} means?

Any explanation would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const variablename = (data) => asycn(dispatch) => {}
```

This is a small version of Redux Thunk.
In FP terms, thunk is a higher-order function that returns another function. Your function can be written like this,

```
function variableName(data){
 return async function(dispatch){
   
 }
}
```

When you read Redux docs, you will come to know this is one of the middlewares used to write async calls in a synchronized way.
For instance,
like you wrote:

```
dispatch(saveShippingAddress(formData))
```

then in
saveShippingAddress

```
dispatch({type:actions.SHIPPING_ADDRESS_SAVE, payload: formData})
```

This is your synchronized call.

For a moment, just assume you would be making a backend API call inside saveShippingAddress.
Even in that case, you would be writing the same

```
dispatch(saveShippingAddress(formData))
```

from your component.

But in your action file, you would have written something like:

```
try{
 axios.get(MY_API).then((resp)=>{
   dispatch({type:actions.SHIPPING_ADDRESS_SAVE, payload: resp.data})
 })
}catch(e){

}
```

So you see, you have got consistency in your component while calling any action.
For in-depth understanding, please go thru this.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34599594/2983489