# How can I use my action from redux without mapDispatchtoProps but with useDispatch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

This is my redux/main/actions where I set my state.

```
export const setInfo = (data) => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: t.SET_LOA,
    payload: data
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about something like this?

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()
// ...
dispatch(setInfo(data))
```

Comment: yeah exactly. but do we really need to dispatch once again though it has been already done in the export function.

Comment: Well this is the syntax of redux-thunk. I would recommend reading about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34599594/11872581. It explains why this is written the way that it is.