# React Redux server render but client side fetch data

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, isomorphic-javascript

I am having server render on a demo react application of mine. Although it works if i refresh the page on a url to fetch the doctor like /doctor/:id if i am at /login and try to go to /doctor/123456 the doctor property is empty and (this.props.doctor.name.first) fails.

What is a good approach to use redux to fetch data on these cases?

Code is below

```
import { fetchDoctor } from '../../DoctorActions';
import { getDoctor } from '../../DoctorReducer';

class DoctorDetailPage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.props.doctor.name.first}</div>
        );
    }
}

DoctorDetailPage.need = [params => {
    return this.props.dispatch(fetchDoctor(params.id));
}];

function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
    return {
        doctor: getDoctor(state, props.params.id),
    };
}
DoctorDetailPage.propTypes = {
    doctor: PropTypes.shape({
        insurance: PropTypes.string,
        description: PropTypes.string,
        GUID: PropTypes.string,
        name: PropTypes.shape({
            first: PropTypes.string,
            last: PropTypes.string,
        })
    }),
    dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DoctorDetailPage);
```

REDUCER

```
import { ADD_DOCTOR } from './DoctorActions';

// Initial State
const initialState = { list: [] };

const DoctorReducer = (state = initialState, action = {}) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_DOCTOR:
            return {
                list: [action.doctor, ...state.list],
            };

        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export const getDoctor = (state, id) => {
  return state.doctors.list.filter(doctor => doctor._id === id)[0];
};

export default DoctorReducer;
```

ACTIONS

```
import callApi from '../../util/apiCaller';

// Export Constants
export const ADD_DOCTOR = 'ADD_DOCTOR';

// Export Actions
export function addDoctor(doctor) {
    return {
        type: ADD_DOCTOR,
        doctor,
    };
}

export function addDoctorRequest() {
    return () => {
        return true;
    };
}

export function fetchDoctor(id) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return callApi(`doctors/${id}`)
            .then(res => dispatch(addDoctor(res)));
    };
}
```

LOG ERROR

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Comment: What's the error that is shown in the console?

Comment: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" because doctor is undefined. Fetch on client side fails although server side is working

Comment: Can you switch to the Network tab and tell us if the API call is being made correctly on the client side?

Comment: no is not. It's is like is trying to render before resolving that object. Also the only way around it is to have a componentDidMount function and setState of doctor to empty. This way can show it empty and then replace it with the fetched data. But this is not the redux way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What is a good approach to fetch data in general?

A user friendly approach would be to enter the page `/doctor/123456` wihtout the need of having the doctor available, so user get's instant feedback that his action (navigate me to page x) worked. In `onEnter` method of react-router or in `componentDidMount` you should start an action `fetchDoctor` and in a meanwhile show the user a spinner or a message indicating that the data is being loaded.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
          { this.props.doctor && <div>{this.props.doctor.name.first}</div> }
          { ! this.props.doctor && <YourSpinnerComponent/> }
        </div>
    );
}
```

So the above render method shows something while data is being loaded and when data comes in it displays it without any errors.

#### What is a good approach to fetch data using redux?

**The "good old" way** to handle async operations is to use [`redux-thunk`](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk). You can read this [great SO answer about dispatching asynchronous redux actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411423/how-to-dispatch-a-redux-action-with-a-timeout?answertab=votes#tab-top).

**The latest trend** is to use [`redux-saga`](https://redux-saga.github.io/redux-saga/index.html). It is a library that aims to make side effects (i.e. asynchronous things like data fetching and impure things like accessing the browser cache) in React/Redux applications easier and better. [More about `redux-saga`](https://redux-saga.github.io/redux-saga/index.html).

So in your case, you would create a Saga to handle the fetching.

[More about `redux-thunk` vs `redux-saga` in this great SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34930735/pros-cons-of-using-redux-saga-with-es6-generators-vs-redux-thunk-with-es7-async?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Comment: Thanks for your answer that worked fine. Just to let other users know that the above example would work if you put the return () in a div like ..
return (
   <div>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
    { this.props.doctor && <div>{this.props.doctor.name.first}</div> }
   </div>
  );

Comment: @PanagiotisVrs thanks for the note. I have corrected the answer too.