# Redux - calling a chain of functions in action or reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a logical issue, whether i should make a multiple function calls into response of each callback inside an actions:

```
export const myAction= () => (distaptch, getState) => {
    callFunctionA(function(e){
        if(e){
            dispatch(eventA(e));

            callFunctionB(function(e){

                dispatch(eventB(e));

                callFunctionC(function(e){

                    dispatch(eventC(e));
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

or i might want to move those calls into redux reducers and call every next function from there?

```
const reducer = (state={}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'EVENT_A':

      callFunctionB(action.e);

      return state;
    case 'EVENT_B':

        callFunctionC(action.e);
        return state;   
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Second approach looks to me like anti-pattern which leads to spaghetti code... Maybe i am wrong?

Comment: "Second approach looks to me like anti-pattern" first one looks like callback hell

Comment: @Daniel_L,  u would consider recalling functions from reducers?

Comment: I would consider looking at a library like redux-saga or redux-observable that deals with transforming async actions, because this way you won't end up with easy-to-maintain code.

Comment: @ArkadyB i use thunks and have the promises dispatch actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in assuming that dispatching actions in the reducer is an anti-pattern. The reasons are mentioned pretty succinctly [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730793/dispatch-action-in-reducer).

From the Redux documentation:

> Things you should never do inside a reducer:
>
> Mutate its arguments;
>
> **Perform side effects like API calls and routing transitions;**
>
> (Call non-pure functions, e.g. Date.now() or
>   Math.random().
>
> [...] For now, just remember that the reducer must be
>   pure. Given the same arguments, it should calculate the next state and
>   return it. No surprises. No side effects. No API calls. No mutations.
>   Just a calculation.

You can look into [Redux-Saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) to handle asychronous flow to avoid the callback hell of the actions that you show in your first example.

Comment: It does the same as await/async for thunk?

Comment: Here is a post that details the differences/similarities between async/await with redux-thunk vs redux-saga. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34930735/pros-cons-of-using-redux-saga-with-es6-generators-vs-redux-thunk-with-es7-async/34933395