# How React Redux Using With Thunk And Saga For Scalable Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The benefit of Redux-Saga in comparison to Redux-Thunk?
what is the pupose of redux saga?
what is the purpose of redux thunk?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Redux Thunk:**

Redux Thunk is a middleware that allows you to call the action creators that return a function(thunk) which takes the store’s dispatch method as the argument and which is afterwards used to dispatch the synchronous action after the API or side effects has been finished.

[Here](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks) is the official documentation of Redux Thunk.

Here is an example in Redux Thunk. It’s easy to understand. Instead of returning a simple object as an action, you return a function that handles the async task.

**Example:**

```
// with thunk, instead of returning an object, we can return a     function (for async tasks)
const callHttp = () => {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(beforeCall())
    axios.get()
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch(afterSuccess(res.data))
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      dispatch(afterFail(error.message))
    })
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    deletePost: (id) => dispatch(callHttp())
  }
}
```

**Redux Saga:**

Redux Saga is also a middleware library that helps us with API calls or side effects. Redux Saga uses an ES6 feature called ‘Generators’ which helps us to write asynchronous code.

Generators are the functions that came with ECMA Script 6. And the amazing part is that the generator functions can be paused in between the execution or even can be exited and later re-entered.

you can learn saga from their official documentation [Redux Saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial/)

Here is the image that can help you better understand.
[image]

To understand more visit [what-is-the-difference-between-redux-thunk-and-redux-saga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50285972/what-is-the-difference-between-redux-thunk-and-redux-saga)