# how to make async call in react-redux hooks with thunk?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-thunk

I starting to learn hooks. But i dont understand how right work with async call.
Earlier i was use

```
import * as actionQR from "../actions/qr";
...
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actionQR: bindActionCreators(actionQR, dispatch),
    }
}
```

and after this call my `this.props.actionQR.myFunc()`, but what I should do with useDispatch()?
if I just call

```
import {foo} from "../actions/qr";
...
useDispatch(foo());
```

then my `foo()` dont `console.log(2)`

```
export const foo = () => {
    console.log(1);
    return (dispatch) => {
        console.log(2);
      }
}
```

Im using thunk

```
import createRootReducer from './reducers/index';
...
const store = createStore(createRootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `useDispatch()` hook will return a reference to the `dispatch` function, you don't pass to it an action, you get the `dispatch` reference and pass to it (the `dispatch`) the action.

So basically it should look something like this:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()
dispatch(foo())
```

You can get more details from the [react-redux DOCS](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#usedispatch)

Comment: I think the OP meant to ask for a way to bind a hook to the redux-thunk action creator, not to do dispatches directly.

Comment: @CarlosJimenezBermudez Thanks. Though the OP used the API in a wrong way, i just showed him/her the way this API should be use. Beside, the OP accepted the answer so i guess i did understand what the OP meant?